# Dart: Synchronous post request

Tags: dart, client, httprequest, synchronous

I would like to send a synchronous POST request from the client-side. According to the documentation we can use the 'async' named parameter:

https://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/#saving-objects-on-the-server

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/programming-languages";
request.open("POST", url, async: false);
```

But the above example throws the following syntax error:

*The keywords 'async', 'await', and 'yield' may not be used as identifiers in an asynchronous or generator function.*

How can I send a synchronous POST request?

**UPDATE (27 May, 20:23)**

I found a workaround to solve this problem:

```
Future<String> deleteItem(String id) async {
    final req = new HttpRequest()
      ..open('POST', 'server/controller.php')
      ..send({'action': 'delete', 'id': id});
    // wait until the request have been completed
    await req.onLoadEnd.first;
    // oh yes
    return req.responseText;
}
```

But I don't like the above solution because it doesn't seem elegant enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `postFormData()` instead of `send()`. For example:

```
final req = await HttpRequest
    .postFormData(url, {'action': 'delete', 'id': id});
return req.responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with this named parameter https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24637

Comment: This was an issue solved by Perl 25 years ago by having sigils on all data, permitting backward compatibility by simultaneously allowing `$print` and `print`, so that new keywords would never conflict with old variable names.  Sigils were there for a reason, folks.

Comment: Perl also introduced a few new problems as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<String> deleteItem(String id) async {
final req = new HttpRequest()
  ..open('POST', 'server/controller.php')
  ..send({'action': 'delete', 'id': id});
// wait until the request have been completed
await req.onLoadEnd.first;
// oh yes
return req.responseText;
```

}

this one is the point, where sometimes you need "PUT" or "DELETE"

Comment: `async` and `await` doesn't make anything synchronous. It's just more convenient syntax to cope with async execution.